# Solving a Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through my textbook, and it gives the linear system:

$a+2b-c+d=0$

$2a+3b+c+d=0$

$3a-b+2c+d=0$

It doesn't explain how this is solved, they just provide the answer which they come up with:

$a = -\frac{9}{16}t$

$b = -\frac{1}{16}t$

$c = \frac{5}{16}t$

$d = t$

I don't understand how the author came up with this solution, could anyone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use Gaussian elimination to solve the system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & - 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This can be done by applying Gaussian elimination to row reduce the augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & - 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
3 & -1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As I mentioned in a previous answer, if you are not familiar with this, this Wikipedia article is quite helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination and you may also find Paul's notes useful: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrix.aspx.

Of course, we can see that you have a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns, and so (at least) one variable must be free and hence determines the scaling parameter which determines the other 3 values.